# CodeIgniter Render 404 on form inserting into database

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I am new to CodeIgniter. I'm attending at the tutorial on the official site, I followed all steps but when I fill in the form my data and click the button in order to populate the database, it renders me a 404 page and the URL changes in `http://localhost/cod_ign/index.php/news/localhost/cod_ign/index.php/news/create` and doesn't push data in the database.

I think that the problem is on the route.php but I don't know, I have my route.php like the tutorial file.

Can you help me?

Comment: it is obviously a wrong route. I recommend first learning vanilla php there you will get some skills for debugging. otherwise without any code there is nothing we can do

Comment: Ok, just i put the code that give the tutorial. Perhaps I have to stop programming :) if i can't copy paste !

Comment: make sure you have set base url correct

Comment: On $config['base_url'] I have 'localhost/cod_ign'

Comment: try set it as `http://localhost/cod_ign`

Comment: @JoshuaKisubi Don't forget the trailing slash i.e. http://localhost/cod_ign/

Comment: Also can you show what your action is for the form. It will most likely need a leading /.

Comment: Thank you @joshuaKisubi ! With http:// works !